# Why wasn't I given reputation points for answer being accepted?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, reputation, accepted-answer, reputation-history

I answered the question *[Calculating a mean from a data frame with blanks with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64149506/calculating-a-mean-from-a-data-frame-with-blanks-with-r/)* which was accepted, but I did not get 15 reputation points for it. Although, I got 30 points for three upvotes there.

I don't see the points here:

[image]

But I do see it under my profile here:

[image]

But again not under the reputation tab.

[image]

I waited for some time for this to correct itself, but nothing changed. Was the answer accepted during something else was going on and hence, it was not captured?

Comment: What does https://stackoverflow.com/reputation tell you?

Comment: It doesn't have the complete question-wise details for today but it shows - `rep today: 160` meaning it is counting the 15 points from that answer I think.

Comment: Okay, this is indeed weird. The OP even has a +2 accepted answer event in their reputation tab. But the +15 accepted answer event is missing from your reputation page, and I can’t find any reason or rhyme as to why that would be the case.

Comment: I'm seeing the accept under the reputation tab now. [shouldiblamecaching](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/)?

Comment: I love the smell of caching in the morning.

Comment: @RonakShah Revisiting this. It looks like this was a caching problem, but want to confirm with you if you've noticed any further mishaps with reputation activity. If not, will resolve to [meta-tag:status-completed] or other.

Comment: @JonChan Hi...I haven't experienced any other issue like this after this incident.